# Creating an additional mainmenu in another module

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to create a horizontal menu, just like the one in my main menu position (in fact I want it to look identical). I have setup a menu module in the position I would like and added the class-suffix that applies to my main menu. The first 'level' of the menu displays correctly, however, the dropdown box submenu items are covered by the modules below so I cannot see or choose the items. I just want a menu that looks identical to my mainmenu in another position. Is there an easy way to do this? Do I need to change how the position 'styles' menus and if so, where do I do this (css files, php files)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code or link to the page?

Comment: This would entirely depend on the theme that you are using and how it is configured. It sounds like there may be a css setting in the template that is preventing the dropdown from appearing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Bear with me as I am new to Joomla. I have several css files I can show, one being menu.css, would this one be of any help? If so, how do I display it correctly in this comment box? Other css files include: layout.css, template.php, base.css

Comment: using Themeforest framework

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds like you have a z-index issue with the modules below the menu. Depending on the position of the code and the CSS you will need to make some changes to put the menu module above the items that are covering the dropdown menu.

If you want a specific answer then you need to give us a link to the page.